# Unity 2D sprite support?

Tags: unity

Does Unity 3D support 2D sprites yet? I know that they have mentioned it in a blog post but I don't know if that feature has gone live yet

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a topic that is highly localized in time and will very quickly become irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2D sprites, or point sprites in 3D?

3D: Unity supports point sprites as billboards, by rotating the necessary geometry to face the camera; presumably point sprites could also be implemented more efficiently via a fragment shader.

2D: Unity 2D Toolkit OR Sprite Manager are the basic go-to points for anyone wanting to write 2D games under Unity.

P.S. The [feature you mention](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/08/28/unity-native-2d-tools/) is expected to be in the 4.3 release, which isn't out just yet.